# GestureRecognizer action not firing when connected from Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

So I'm following the [Official Apple iOS tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1) to a T.

I've added a `GestureRecognizer` to my `ImageView`, and have CTRL+Click dragged an action to my `ViewController`. From the Interface Builder, everything seems to be going well:

[image]

My following wired action (in `ViewController.swift`, pared down for simplicity):

```
@IBAction func tapImageView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("clicked")
}
```

However, when I click on the corresponding image, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: set your imageview's user interaction to enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to enable the user interaction for the image view within the storyboard.[image: Enabling user inter]

Answer (score 3):

So you have to add One more line in your viewDidLoad() that is,

```
ImageViewname.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

hope this is help Full you.